# Should I implement interface members explicitly or implicitly?

Tags: c#

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841182/how-not-to-implement-a-function-of-an-interface-in-class/1841782) and [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841182/how-not-to-implement-a-function-of-an-interface-in-class/1841782#1841782) got me wondering: How *do* you decide whether to use an explicit or implicit implementation when implementing methods of an interface?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(personally) I only see a need for explicit implementations when there is a clash between methods with the same signature.

For example, when implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, you should implement 2 methods `GetEnumerator()` which have the same signature, except for the return type. So you'll have to implement `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` explicitly:

```
public abstract class MyClass<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ...;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() // explicit implementation required
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Another use for an explicit implementation is if you don't want the method to be called through an object instance, but only through an interface. I personally think this doesn't make much sense, but in some very rare cases, it can be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Philippe's answer is a practical, one, however, there are architectural considerations as well.

Interfaces are used to make classes compatible so that they can be consumed by other objects.  If only those consuming objects need the functionality of the interface, then it should be restricted so - by the principle of least privilege.  If would be unnecessary to expose that interface method to all other users of the class.

Paul

Comment: Can you think of an example where this might apply?

Comment: Web dev.  If a class is designed to provide services across the web, there may be methods for say identity verification in a security interface that may be used in no other circumstances (locally).  This is a little know C# feature that I think is often ignored.  Other examples out there?

Answer (score 1):

Another case for explicit interfaces is where the object needs to implement an interface to accept calls from an internal object, but you don't want to expose those as part of your API.